# Akka Remote Actor - actorSelection failed to be remote

Tags: scala, akka, remote-actors

I am building an API service on Scala that should call a remote actor for a specific microservice.

Documentation talks about that:

```
val remoteSelection = context.system.actorSelection("akka.tcp://RemoteSystem@127.0.1.1:2552/user/EmailActor").resolveOne()
```

However, when I implement it on my code, I always get the current local ActorSystem as below:

> Failure(akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for:
>   ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://LocalSystem/deadLetters)

where LocalSystem is the previous ActorSystem that I used.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your remote system located .. it is on the same system or different system ?

Comment: @pamu The remote system is in a separated folder and I run each application in a separated terminal by SBT RUN

Comment: 127.0.1.1... shouldn't that be 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @Totozy how did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error does say that there is no actor with this path in this system. Are you sure that this actor is created before calling it?

You could log its path when it is created (`println(self.path)`) to verify this.

Comment: Thanks @Simon, 

I put the println and I get this: akka://WebSystem/user/emailActor
It seems that the actorSelection does nothing.
Did I miss something to call the remote actor?